# Reflection: How to invoke method without parameter properly?

Tags: java, reflection, methods, invoke

I am trying to invoke a method by Java reflection, which don't have any parameter as:

```
Method getSelectedCriteriaMethod = multipleSorting.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSelectedCriteria", null);
EstimateSortField selectedCriteria = (EstimateSortField)getSelectedCriteriaMethod.invoke(multipleSorting, null);
```

This is working, but I am getting compiler warning:

```
warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to java.lang.Class<?> for a varargs call
non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
```

What is the right way to invoke a method which don't have any parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getDeclaredMethod("getSelectedCriteria");
invoke(multipleSorting);
```

Comment: I try the same thing and got `Note: file.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.` and when enabling lint `warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to getDeclaredMethod(String,Class<?>...) as a member of the raw type Class`

Comment: @jcubic Seems like you have done something like `Class cls;` instead of `Class<Blah> cls;`. Maybe you can ask a separate question if I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply say

```
selectedCriteria.invoke(multipleSorting);
```